# Printing or Echoing message in html page from javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following script

```
function validateEmailp() {
var messagemail = document.getElementById('emailerrorz').innerText;
var two = document.getElementById('email').value;
var first = two.split("@")[1];
var badEmails = ["gmail.com", "yahoo.com"]
if (badEmails.indexOf(first) != -1) {
        document.getElementById("email").value = ""; //this works
    messagemail = 'We do not accept free e-mails'; //this doesn't
    return false;
    }   
return true;
}
```

and HTML

```
<td>{EMAILFIELD}<span id="emailerrorz"></span></td>
```

and {EMAILFIELD} is in PHP

```
<input id="email" class="txt" type="text" name="email" size="25" value="" maxlength="255" onblur="validateEmailp()"></input>
```

But it doesn't work for me on printing the error in the span id. It only works on resetting the value from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `var messagemail = document.getElementById('emailerrorz').innerText;` your variable stores a string with that content.

When you `var messagemail = document.getElementById('emailerrorz');` your variable stores a object/element and then you can use the property `.innerText`

So use:

```
var messagemail = document.getElementById('emailerrorz');
// rest of code
messagemail.innerText = 'We do not accept free e-mails';
```

Answer (score 1):

Properties don't work this way. You want:

```
 document.getElementById('emailerrorz').innerText = 'We do not accept free e-mails'
```

or

```
  var messagemail = document.getElementById('emailerrorz');
  ....
  messagemail.innerText = etc
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MJXEg/

Comment: @Adrian: see the fiddle link

Comment: When i click on another field besides getting it reset it should also print the error aside on the e-mail field. But from what i can see in the fiddle, it doesn't to.

Comment: It seams that you need to add textcontent instead of innertext.